# How can I block the News app on iOS?

Tags: ios, apple-news

I need to block the app. Which domain names does it use? Can I use content restriction like Safari? Can I block the IP addresses in my router?

Comment: If upgrading to iOS 10 is an option for you, the app can be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to prevent usage of the app completely, you can enable restrictions (Settings > General > Restrictions) and turn off the toggle for News.

iOS 10 also lets you delete default apps like News, but keep in mind that it could be re-downloaded from the App Store (unless you enable the restriction for Installing Apps too).